# Is there a place to download libgomp.spec?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have been installing distro after distro of Ming and for whatever godforsaken reason none of them come with the libgomp.spec file required to use Open MP.

Is there a place where I can just download the file and stick it in the folder somewhere? I can't find the file online anywhere.

Comment: It was included with the version I downloaded from their site. I found it in `MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.2`

Answer (score 1):

Since no one answered, I'll post something I found.

This link appears to have an attachment you can download.

[MingW Forums](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/I-recieve-quot-libgomp-spec-quot-not-found-when-linking-and-compining-with-fopenmp-td31223.html)

Another forum thread:
http://openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=183

Apparently the file exists at the usr/lib64 and you need to copy it to a different directory (usr/lib or usr/local/lib)

Comment: Now it says:

c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgomp
c:/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about that to help more.